# ssh TUNNEL in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, ssh-tunnel, vscode-remote-ssh

I followed this official guide: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh and I was able to setup my dev environment in vscode via remote ssh to my server.

Now the issue is that I need to do SSH tunnelling trough my server to access another server on a private network.

Normally, from my computer I just run:

```bash
ssh -i my_first_key -t me@my_first_server.com ssh -i my_second_key me@my_second_server.com
```

How do I replicate the same behaviour in vscode so that I can work on my code hosted on `my_second_server` from vscode on my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to config the ssh proxy in the `~/.ssh/config` file.

See more on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234903/correct-ssh-config-file-settings-to-tunnel-to-a-3rd-machine .